# Checkbox size in Fluent UI Northstar

Tags: css, reactjs, checkbox, fluentui-react

What is the proper way to control the size of checkboxes in Fluent UI Northstar?

I have tried adjusting the font size and the height, but it only acts on the label, not the box itself. And I didn't find anything in the [documentation](https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/0.52.0/components/checkbox/definition).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this to be a general styling that applies to all checkboxes rendered inside your provider, you can modify the checkbox component-style in the theme you pass into the provider.

Create your own theme, apply the styles you want and then merge it into the theme that you are currently using

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRFyN.png)

```
import { Provider, teamsTheme, mergeThemes, ThemeInput } from '@fluentui/react-northstar';
const myTheme: ThemeInput = {
componentStyles: {
    Checkbox: {
        root: {
            //will apply styles to the root-container component
        },
        checkbox: {
            backgroundRepeat: "repeat",
        },
        label: {
            //will apply styles to the label
        },
    }
}}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider theme={mergeThemes(teamsTheme, myTheme)}>           
        <AppContainer>
            <Component title={title} isOfficeInitialized={isOfficeInitialized} />
        </AppContainer>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

the checkbox rendering issue in the picture is fixed by setting:

> backgroundRepeat: "repeat"

Answer (score 0):

Style the CheckBox as follows:

```
 componentStyles: {
 Checkbox: {
    root: {
        
    },
    checkbox: {
        height: '20px',
        width: '20px',
    },  
  }
 },
```